# Convert .csv file into 2-dimensional array in Excel VBA memory

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, csv

I have a .csv file that looks like this:

```
Unit,,PU,,,,,Start Date & Time,,,5/20/2020 17:32,,

Name,,PNR15.5,,,,,,,,,,

ID,,TEST52020,,,,,End Date & Time,,,,,

No.,,77,,,,,,,,,,

,,,,,,,,,,,,

Phase name,,Start Time,,End Time,,,,,,,,

C,,,,,,,,,,,,

S,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

I am trying to convert it to a 2-dimensional array, in Excel VBA memory, that can be referenced by Excel cells.

There are hundreds of CSV files.

I tried line by line, but element2(k,l) line gives me an error.

```
Dim ArrayOfElements As Variant
Dim line, element, element2() As Variant
Dim k, l as Integer
k=0
Do While filename <> vbNullString
    Open path & filename For Input As #1
            
    Do While Not EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, line
        
        ArrayOfElements = Split(line, ",")
        k = k + 1
        l = 1
        For Each element In ArrayOfElements
            element2(k, l) = element
        l = l + 1
        Next
    Loop
    Close #1
Loop
```

Eventually, I want: Cells(1,1).Value = element2(1,1).

Comment: You haven't sized `element2()` before you begin populating it.  The easier way is to open the CSV in Excel, and read the data from the worksheet. Then you don't need to worry about how to correctly parse the CSV format (such as how to handle field values with embedded spaces for example)

Comment: I agree with @TimWilliams.  Might need to test it, but conceptually, it might be faster and simpler to read the entire CSV file into a temporary worksheet using`Workbooks.OpenText` or a Query and then read it into a vba array in a single step (e.g `myArr = UsedRange`) and then delete the sheet.

Comment: I agree.  If we still want to use this code, how do I size element2() as it goes through each element?  I could potentially size the array in the beginning, but I would like to do it as we go through each element.

Comment: I think I got it:
Do While filename <> vbNullString
        Open path & filename For Input As #1
                
        Do While Not EOF(1)
            Line Input #1, line
            
            ArrayOfElements = Split(line, ",")
            k = k + 1
            l = 1
            For Each element In ArrayOfElements
                ReDim element2(k, l)
                element2(k, l) = element
                MsgBox element2(k, l)
            l = l + 1
            Next
        Loop
        Close #1
    Loop

Comment: If you want to resize an array but not lose its contents you need to use `Redim Preserve` , but the issue is you can only resize the *last* dimension (so you can't add more "rows")

Comment: ah okay, that's annoying.  I found another easy way.  I basically cheated and just sized the array in the beginning (element2(50,13)) to make it easier because I know the CSV size to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

I'd still recommend reading the file onto a hidden, temporary worksheet, then directly into the array (eg `ArrayOfElements = myRange`) but using a variation of your existing code, here is an example using a Collection object for intermediate storage:

```
    Open Path & Filename For Input As #1
    Set col = New Collection

    Do While Not EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, line
        col.Add Split(line, ",") 'Note that Split results in a 0-based array
    Loop
    Close #1


ReDim ArrayOfElements(1 To col.Count, 1 To UBound(col(1)) + 1)
l = 0

For Each element In col
    l = l + 1
    For k = 0 To UBound(element)
        ArrayOfElements(l, k + 1) = element(k)
    Next k
Next element
```

[image]

Comment: Ah thank you!  Do you know if it runs faster using collection vs. what I wrote?

Comment: @ricky88 I have no idea. You'd have to time it. My sense is that using the collection object would slow things down compared with creating a fixed size array. The **advantage** of this method is that you don't need to know the size of the array in advance.